# JavaScript expose prototype properties

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

If I have a base function constructor such as

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.bar = 'Hello';
```

and I do

```
var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo);
```

the output is

```
{}
```

Is it possible, without manually setting `this.bar = 'Hello';` in the constructor, to expose the prototype properties to instances? In other words, is it possible to preset a prototype and have the properties be exposed as `ownProperties` to the object instance of that prototype?

The expected outoupt should be

```
{ bar: 'Hello' }
```

Comment: What appears in the console depends on the browser. In chrome I see *`Foo {bar: "Hello"}`* ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y6N2J/)).

Comment: No, they can't be exposed as *ownProperties*, because they're not *ownProperties*. An *ownProperty* is one that is not inherited. If this is just for display, make a custom method that serializes the object however you want.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I haven't specified a browser because this is actually in Node.js. I guess it's a node problem, then?

Answer (score 1):

You have done it correctly, just do

```
console.log(foo.bar);
```

and you will see what you want. You saw `{}` in some browser just because the way it is displayed in some browser. On Safari for example, you can "dig into" the object and see the `bar` when you follow the `__proto__` chain.

`bar` is not a `foo`'s "own property" this way.  In order for it to be `foo`'s own property, you need to set `foo.bar` so that it is `foo`'s own property.

Explanation:

1. `foo` is a variable which is a reference to an object (let's call this object A).
2. This object has a "[[Prototype]] internal property" or `__proto__` property as seen in the Firefox or Chrome browser.
3. `foo.__proto__` is a reference to an object, (let's call this object B), which is exactly what Foo.prototype is a reference to.
4. when you say `foo.bar`, first the JavaScript engine looks in object A as to whether the property `bar` exists, and since it does not, it will follow `foo.__proto__` and look at object B, and finds it, and return the result to you.

Note that [`foo.__proto__` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). It is not a standard, but currently works in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari to experiment with your code, but on IE and in general, you need to do `Object.getPrototypeOf(foo)` to see it.

Answer (score -1):

> In other words, is it possible to preset a prototype and have the properties be exposed as ownProperties to the object instance of that prototype?

You can't do it directly but [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object can intercept `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` and similar.

If you want to support browsers other than Firefox, you have to write your own function for retrieving properties (you can also override `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` but I don't recommend it - *don't modify object you don't own*).